# Find all $n\in\mathbb N$, $n>3$ such that $p(n)=2n+16$, where $p(n)$ is the product of all the prime numbers less than $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, divisibility

> Find all $n\in\mathbb N$, $n>3$ such that $p(n)=2n+16$, where $p(n)$ is the product of all the prime numbers less than $n$.

E.g. $p(7)=2\cdot3\cdot5$ (and $n=7$ is a solution).

Let $$p(n)=2\cdot3\cdot p_3\cdot p_4\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k$$Then $n\in(p_k;p_{k+1}]$.

And $$2n+16=2\cdot3\cdot p_3\cdot p_4\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k$$ $$n+8=3\cdot p_3\cdot p_4\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k$$

Therefore $$n\equiv 1\pmod 3$$

And we know that $n$ is odd. Hence the number is of the form $n=6l+1$ for some natural number $l$. So $$2l+3=p_3\cdot p_4\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k$$

I wonder if we could get to some kind of a restriction, i.e. $p(n)\le a$ for some natural number $a$. Or something else. I'd appreciate some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Not only $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$, but generally $n\equiv -8 \pmod{p_i}$, for $i=2,\ldots,k$, where $p_k=\max\{p_i: p_k\leq n\}$.

Comment: @frabala It should be $p_k=\max\{p_i: p_k< n\}$, not $p_k=\max\{p_i: p_k\leq n\}$

Comment: @mathh, yes you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is probably more what you are looking for.

As you already noticed, $3\mid n-1$. Suppose $n>13$, so $n-10$ is not prime.

Now $p(n-10)\mid p(n)=2(n-10)+36$. From here we see that every prime divisor $q\mid n-10$ satisfies $q\mid p(n-10)$ and $q\mid n-10$ so $q\mid36$. This means $n-10$ is of the form $2^a3^b$.

Because $4,9\nmid p(n)$ we have $a=0$ and $b=1$. Then $n=13$, which contradicts our assumption $n>13$.

So $n\leq13$, and it's not hard to check that only $7$ works.

Comment: How did you obtain $2(n-10)+16\mid 2(n-10)+36$? There is not necessarily a relation like $p(n-10)=2(n-10)+16$, right?

Comment: @barto Yes, I rushed too much and never went through the proof carefully.

Comment: $2\mid p(n)$; $3\mid p(n)$; $4\nmid p(n)$; $9\nmid p(n)$, but what tells you that $a=0$ and $b=1$? I can't see how this is obtained.

Comment: Well, $p(n)=2(n-10)+2^23^2$ so $4,9\nmid2(n-10)$.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to obtain the lower bound $n^2<p(n)$ for all $n\ge 8$. See for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate).  It follows that $2n+16>n^2$, which clearly excludes all $n\ge 8$. So it is enough to check the formula for $n=4,5,6,7,8$. Indeed, only for $n=7$ there is equality.

Comment: Too bad no one has shown me a proof that doesn't use the postulate. This problem is supposed to be solvable using my own knowledge only. And I haven't even been taught about logarithms yet.

Comment: You'll definitely need something vaguely as strong as Bertrand's postulate – say $p \in (n,n^2)$ – in order to show that $2n+16$ is too *small* to be equal to $p(n)$.  But see barto's solution which makes better use of the exact equality $p(n) = 2n+16$.

Answer (score 1):

[Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (also known as Chebyshev's theorem) states that for every integer $x>1$ there is a prime between $x$ and $2x$. Applying this for $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$ and $\lfloor\frac n4\rfloor$, we get an interesting lower bound on $p(n)$. I think you can continue, knowing this...

Comment: Too bad no one has shown me a proof that doesn't use the postulate. This problem is supposed to be solvable using my own knowledge only. And I haven't even been taught about logarithms yet.